# Getting entire tree with webs, subwebs and lists fails if there is no access to atleast one teamsite

Tags: list, permissions, site-collection, sub-site, team-sites

So I have a collection of some teamsites and subsites with their lists. And if I for example as a user don't have permissions for one subsite, then I have an exception after sending a request:

```
        var rootWeb = ClientContext.Site.RootWeb;

        ClientContext.Load(
            rootWeb,
            w => w.Title,
            w => w.Url,
            w => w.Lists,
            w => w.Lists.Include(
                list => list.RootFolder.Name,
                list => list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl,
                list => list.ParentWeb.Url
            ),
            w => w.Id,
            w => w.Webs.Include(
                subWeb => subWeb.Title,
                subWeb => subWeb.Url,
                subWeb => subWeb.Lists,
                subWeb => subWeb.Lists.Include(
                    list => list.RootFolder.Name,
                    list => list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl,
                    list => list.ParentWeb.Url
                ),
                subWeb => subWeb.Id
            )
        );
        ClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

because of that I can't get entire structure.

How can I get entire structure if I don't have permissions for one subsite?
Thanks

Comment: One way might be to split it up in seperate loads that you run recursively.

Comment: THanks for your answer. YEs, I thought about this, but it will be not very good for performance, so I thought there is another solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to utilize [Web.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.getsubwebsforcurrentuser(v=office.15).aspx) instead [Web.Webs property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.webs(v=office.15).aspx) since it returns the *security trimmed* (the current users has access) list of sub sites.

**Modified example**

```
var objectsToInclude = new Expression<Func<Web, object>>[]
     {
           w => w.Title,
           w => w.Url,
           w => w.Lists,
           w => w.Lists.Include(
           list => list.RootFolder.Name,
           list => list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl,
           list => list.ParentWeb.Url)
     };

//1.Load root web
ctx.Load(ctx.Site.RootWeb, objectsToInclude);
var subWebs = ctx.Site.RootWeb.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser(null);
//2.Load sub webs
ctx.Load(subWebs, wcol => wcol.Include(objectsToInclude));
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

> Note: both [Web.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.getsubwebsforcurrentuser(v=office.15).aspx) and [Web.Webs
>   property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.webs(v=office.15).aspx) returns only **one level beneath** web sites, nothing
>   more. So, if you are interested in returning the whole web tree
>   structure, the example will be different.

Comment: we use two levels max. I've tried your solution but as the result it's throwed the exception little bit later

Comment: How can I get the tree with two levels of depth ?